# Showing a block matrix (Reflector) is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, orthogonality

Let $\hat{Q_i}$ be the householder reflector for the vector $A_{i:k,k}$, which is just $i$ through $k$ elements of column $i$. Now let:

$${Q_i} = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{i-1} & 0\\
0 & \hat{Q_i}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $I_{i-1}$ is the (i-1) identity matrix. Prove that ${Q_i}$ is symmetric and orthogonal.

OK, so clearly ${Q_i}$ is symmetric. To show its orthogonal, I need to show that ${Q_i}{Q_i}^T$ is the identity. So since ${Q_i}$ is symmetric, then I just get the following:

$${Q_i}{Q_i} = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{i-1}I_{i-1} & 0\\
0 & \hat{Q_i}\hat{Q_i}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which reduces to:
$${Q_i}{Q_i} = \begin{pmatrix}
I_{i-1} & 0\\
0 & \hat{Q_i}\hat{Q_i}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I'm stuck here. There might be some property of Householder reflectors I'm completely forgetting. And honestly, I have no idea if we're actually allowed to multiply block matrices in the way I did. Can anybody help? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Householder reflectors are orthogonal.
\begin{align}
&\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)\\
&=I-4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{v(v^Tv)v^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\\
&=I-4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{vv^T}{(v^Tv)}\\
&=I
\end{align}

Comment: Crap. I forgot that. So then I just need to replace the lower diagonal with I, and that makes it orthogonal right?

Comment: Yup, you are right.